# Why is this SQL query ordering incorrectly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the following query to "reorder" an updated table alphabetically. There's a column called nOrder that's supposed to be in sequential order. I'm updating that column as follows:

(edited: forgot to include `AND @zone = zone` in my question, but the same problem is occurring)

```
UPDATE Zones
SET nOrder = 0 WHERE stateKey = @key

DECLARE @zone INT
SET @zone = 1
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1

WHILE @zone < 4
    BEGIN
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 cDisplay FROM Zones WHERE stateKey = @key AND zone = @zone AND nOrder = 0)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE Zones
                SET nOrder = @i
                WHERE cDisplay = (SELECT TOP 1 cDisplay FROM Zones WHERE stateKey = @key AND zone = @zone AND nOrder = 0 ORDER BY cDisplay)
                SET @i += 1
            END
            SET @zone += 1
            set @i = 1
    END
```

The table then becomes:

```
FK zone                cDisplay                nOrder
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
10  3    MD: CAROLINE, DORCHESTER, KENT          40
10  3    MD: QUEEN ANNE'S                        41
10  3    MD: SOMERSET, TALBOT, WILCOMICO         42
10  3    ME: PORTLAND                            43
10  3    ME: YORK                                44
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
10  3    TX: COUNTIES NORTH OF HOUSTON           99
10  3    TX: DALLAS-FORT WORTH OUTER SUBURBAN   100
10  3    TX: EL PASO                            101
10  3    TX: MATAGORDA AND VICTORIA COUNTIES    102
10  3    TX: NORTHEAST COUNTIES                 103
10  3    TX: SAN ANTONIO OUTER SUBURBAN AREAS   104
10  3    TX: SOUTHERN TEXAS                      43   --???
10  3    TX: TYLER                              105
                          .
                          .
                          .
                          .
```

"FK" is actually "stateKey", but that doesn't fit.

why would this record be out of order? It doesn't make much sense to me that this would happen.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `select` statement with `order by` clause?

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but the only order by clause I see is to order by cDisplay, and if I'm reading correctly, then 'SOUTHERN TEXAS' belongs right after 'SAN ANTONIO...'

Comment: The posted  table is returned from `SELECT * FROM Zones WHERE FK = 10 ORDER BY zone, cDisplay`

Comment: the question is why is the row containing `SOUTHERN TEXAS` not updating `nOrder` correctly. My query (the first part of my question) is updating all but this record correctly.

Comment: So nOrder ISN'T an order clause, only zone and cDisplay which matches the returned data

Comment: @Mike, please read the question. This isn't about a read query but an update query.

Comment: Maybe `WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 cDisplay FROM Zones WHERE stateKey = key AND nOrder = 0)` should be `WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 cDisplay FROM Zones WHERE stateKey = **@key** AND nOrder = 0)`

Comment: We do read the question - you just keep editing it after someone makes a comment! :-)

Comment: You MUST use an ORDER BY clause any time you use "SELECT TOP..."  otherwise you get an undefined ordering that can be anything the SQL Optimizer wants.

Comment: What relevance does `@zone` have? You increment it but never use it.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I forgot to include this in my question. I edited it to show how it is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a much easier way to do this?  I think you want:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      select z.*, row_number() over (partition by zone order by cDisplay) as seqnum
      from zones z
      where stateKey = @key AND nOrder = 0
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    set nOrder = seqnum;
```

The variable `@zone` is set but not used in your code (at least, it doesn't affect the update).  I'm not sure what it should be doing -- but I suspect that is related to the problem with your code.  In any case, using a CTE and ranking function is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: @JosephNields - Yes it is if you are on 2005+ the syntax should be `partition by zone order by cDisplay` though (no comma).

Comment: @NoDisplayName . . . Thank you very much.  I appreciate small changes (changing my indentation style is another matter ;).

Answer (score -1):

You MUST use an ORDER BY clause any time you use "SELECT TOP..." otherwise you get an undefined ordering that can be anything the SQL Optimizer wants.

Comment: Actually, the `TOP 1` is quite redundant in an `exists` subquery.  The `order by` is not necessary there.  So, I guess "MUST" is a bit strong.  (Note:  I did not downvote; I'm only explaining the issue.)

Comment: Well, if you're selecting TOP anything, you need an ORDER BY or the TOP isn't guaranteed to give you what you expect.  It might NOW, but isn't guaranteed in the future.  But you're right that if it's buried in an IF EXISTS, then it's kind of redundant to begin with.  But it doesn't change the fact that using SELECT TOP without an ORDER BY is bad practice, period.  I only added as an answer because the original poster asked me to. I put it in a comment above first.

Comment: realistically I could just delete the `TOP` statement in the exists. But this is only being ran once and acts on about 25,000 records, so efficiency isn't a huge concern.